# Rotate a list-of-list matrix in Clojure

Tags: clojure, matrix

I'm new to Clojure and functional programming in general. I'm at a loss in how to handle this in a functional way.

I have the following matrix:

```
(def matrix [[\a \b \c]
             [\d \e \f]
             [\g \h \i]])
```

I want to transform it into something like this (rotate counterclockwise):

```
((\a \d \g)
 (\b \e \h)
 (\c \f \i ))
```

I've hacked up this bit that gives me the elements in the correct order. If I could collect the data in a string this way I could then split it up with partition. However I'm pretty sure doseq is the wrong path:

```
(doseq [i [0 1 2]]
  (doseq [row matrix]
    (println (get (vec row) i))))
```

I've dabbled with nested map calls but keep getting stuck with that. What's the correct way to build up a string in Clojure or handle this in an even better way?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve sounds like [transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose). I'd suggest

```
(apply map list matrix)
; => ((\a \d \g) (\b \e \h) (\c \f \i))
```

What does it do?

```
(apply map list '((\a \b \c) (\d \e \f) (\g \h \i)))
```

is equivalent to

```
(map list '(\a \b \c) '(\d \e \f) '(\g \h \i))
```

which takes first elements of each of the three lists, calls list on them, then takes second elements, calls list on them... An returns a sequence of all lists which were generated this way.

A couple more examples of both [apply](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply) and [map](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map) can be found on ClojureDocs.

Answer (score 10):

Taking the [matrix transposition](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_transposition#Clojure) solution directly from rosettacode:

`(vec (apply map vector matrix))`

To see what is going on consider:

```
(map vector [\a \b \c] [\d \e \f] [\g \h \i])
```

This will work nicely with arbitrary matrix dimensions although it is not good for significant number crunching, for that you would want to consider using a java based matrix manipulation library from Clojure.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `core.matrix` to do these kind of matrix manipulations very easily. In particular, there is already a `transpose` function that does exactly what you want:

Example:

```
(use 'clojure.core.matrix)

(def matrix [[\a \b \c]
             [\d \e \f]
             [\g \h \i]])

(transpose matrix)
=> [[\a \d \g] 
    [\b \e \h] 
    [\c \f \i]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
(def transposed-matrix (apply map list matrix))
;=> ((\a \d \g) (\b \e \h) (\c \f \i))

(doseq [row transposed-matrix] 
  (doall (map println row)))
```

That produces the same output as your original (printing the columns of `matrix`).